# Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, windows

У меня есть класс, я его компилирую командой `javac Main.java` в ту же директорию, потом пытаюсь запустить командой `java Main`, но компилятор выдает ошибку:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Hello.

Но если я запущу класс такой командой `java cp . Main`, то все заработает. Почему так происходит, почему первым способом у меня не получается запустить программу, раньше получалось?

```
public class Hello{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

компилятор:

```
C:\Users\Dimantik\Desktop>javac Hello.java

C:\Users\Dimantik\Desktop>java Hello
Error: Could not find or load main class Hello

C:\Users\Dimantik\Desktop>java -cp . Hello
Hello World!

C:\Users\Dimantik\Desktop>
```

Answer (score 1):

java -cp вы указвает JVM путь до класса. [Подробнее](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

когда вы компилируете класс через

```
javac Hello.java
```

Посмотрите в C:\Users\Dimantik\Desktop> есть файл Hello.class